# Converting textarea with delimited content to list of entities

Tags: jsf, textarea, converters

As of now I have a simple textarea where I copy/paste a delimited text (using commas).
Each line represents offcourse a new log (in this case a GPS log).

For example:

```
1,15:26:38,5103.5889,400.8531,5
2,15:26:40,5103.5864,400.8449,6
3,15:26:43,5103.5815,400.8335,10
4,15:26:44,5103.5771,400.8259,12
5,15:26:48,5103.5688,400.8123,15
6,15:26:50,5103.5659,400.7946,22
7,15:26:52,5103.5513,400.7545,36
```

So you have here: name, time, latitude, longitude, speed

For now I'm using a simple procedural code like follow:

```
List<GeoCoordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<GeoCoordinate>();
        for (String line : gpsDump.split("\\n")){
            List<String> items = Arrays.asList(line.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
            GeoCoordinate c = new GeoCoordinate();
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(items.get(1));
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GeoTrackController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            c.setDateTime(date);
            c.setLatitude(Float.parseFloat(items.get(2)));
            c.setLongitude(Float.parseFloat(items.get(3)));
            c.setSpeed(Integer.parseInt(items.get(4)));
            coordinates.add(c);
        }
```

But I would like to rewrite this code and make it **more Object Oriented**.
I first thought converting these in my **Entity** class in the setters, but when I received my basic training they discouraged it.

I also read about **converters** but it rather seems it is used for textboxes only.

So what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> *I also read about converters but it rather seems it is used for textboxes only.*

Wrong, you can use them in any [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) implementing [`ValueHolder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/ValueHolder.html) (note that this interface definies a getter and setter to get/set the converter). The [`<h:inputTextarea>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputTextarea.html) which is represented by [`HtmlInputTextarea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlInputTextarea.html) also falls in this category.

```
<h:inputTextarea ... converter="geoCoordinateCsvConverter" />
```

A JSF `Converter` is indeed the right way to convert between Java object based format in model representation and string/charsequence based format in HTML representation.